# Why does my circuit breaker trip when I turn off a surge protector?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

We recently had a room painted, and we asked the painter to replace all of the power outlets and light switches in order to match the trim color (white pieces now instead of beige).

While moving furniture back into place, I plugged a surge protector into its outlet and the circuit breaker tripped. This surge protector-- and the connected 2 computer monitors, docking station (without computer attached), and computer speakers-- has been plugged in to this outlet for months prior without issue. There is not much else on this circuit, only a few LED bulbs and a TV.

Tripping the breaker when plugging in the surge protector seemed strange since the load was the same as before (less actually because the computer was not docked), but is consistent with my understanding of circuit breakers tripping when load increases.

I began to mentally prepare some troubleshooting steps.

I flipped the circuit breaker back on, with the surge protector already plugged in, and everything came on without issue.

I then flipped the switch on the surge protector from "On" to "Off", and the circuit tripped again.

**Why would a circuit trip when turning a surge protector off?**  Especially one that does not have particularly power-hungry devices plugged in.

I'm concerned about what kind of wiring issues may now be present.

After plugging the surge protector back in, turning it on, and then flipping the circuit breaker on, I tried unplugging and re-plugging each cord that is connected to the surge protector, but was unable to cause the circuit to trip any other way. Unfortunately, I don't recall ever turning the surge protector off previously, so am unable to comment on whether the present situation is definitively different from before.

Currently, the surge protector is plugged in, turned on, being used by 2 computers and 2 monitors (via the docking station), and has been functioning seemingly without issue for about 2 days.

Here is a link to a similar surge protector (I'm not sure my exact model, but it looks just like this one): https://www.apc.com/us/en/product/P11U2/apc-performance-surgearrest-11-outlets-with-2-usb-charging-ports-5v-2-4a-in-total-120v/

Comment: Having a painter do electrical work is probably the problem.  I would remove just the faceplate and see if the outlet is close to the box edge or a bare wire is close to the hot.  Type of breaker will help also, just a plain simple breaker or a GFCI breaker.

Comment: @crip659 I agree that the painter is not the best-qualified, however it seemed like simple replacements without much complexity (no new outlets, additional wiring, etc.) and he said that he was comfortable doing it.  At the moment, I'm not actually sure if his work is the issue, but it does seem very probable given the timing of events.

Comment: @crip659 The breaker in question is the common kind that I am familiar with in the US, which is located in the garage and has 2 columns of black switches.  There is not a GFCI outlet on this particular circuit.

Comment: It is simple to replace, but imagine most of us have had the outlet/switch just too close to the box or had a ground wire too close.  Quite a few just tiny things that might cause problems if not caught.  The painter is not really allowed to take money for electrical work(if caught).

Comment: You were asked about a GFCI breaker, and you answered by using the word "breaker" incorrectly and answering an un-asked question about GFCI receptacles.   Put it another way, the breaker switch that is tripping/moving... is there a "TEST" button on that same unit?  (A unit is about 1" tall by 3" wide).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm sorry if I didn't use proper terminology.  "Breaker", as I'm familiar with it, is the box in the garage with numbered switches that control various circuits throughout the house. The "breaker" in my comment is referring to this box- what is the proper name for it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica GFCI, as I understand it, is a breaker that is typically part of an outlet.  I understood crip659's question to be asking whether the tripping was occurring at a central circuit breaker, such as the one in my garage, or at an outlet somewhere on the circuit.  This is what I was attempting to clarify.  Regarding a "Test" button, there are some switches in our breaker in the garage that have one, but I don't believe that the circuit in question does; however, I'm not at home at the moment to confirm.

Comment: @Community I am asking the question highlighted in bold:  "Why would a circuit trip when turning a surge protector off?"

Comment: is it an AFCI breaker?

Comment: The box in the garage is (around here) a service panel or subpanel. The manufacturer calls it a load center.  Each individual "thing that is a switch + overload + short circuit detector and tripper" is properly called a circuit breaker and informally called a breaker.  Some breakers are multi-pole, that's still 1 breaker.

Comment: GFCI is a protection scheme.  It is *typically* an added feature to a circuit breaker, receptacle, or switch.  However standalone GFCI devices also exist, they look like GFCI receptacles with the socket holes blanked.  Any GFCI device will have a "test" button, and some means of resetting it.   Separately, there are AFCI devices which exist in similar form-factors.  We're keen to know about "test" buttons because that may indicate a different cause for the trip (a ground fault or arc fault, respectively.)